# Why am I getting this error when importing a GDB into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, usgs

I've downloaded the Lunar geology data from USGS here:

https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Moon/Geology/Unified_Geologic_Map_of_the_Moon_GIS

While the topography is in ESRI Shapefile format and works just fine in QGIS 3.12, the annotations are in GDB format. When I try and add this as via New Vector Layer > Directory with OpenFileGDB type, I get the following error:

`Invalid Data Source: /GIS/Unified_Geologic_Map_of_the_Moon_GIS/Lunar_GIS/LunarAnnoGeodatabase_08-14-2013.gdb is not a valid or recognized data source.`

Any ideas?

Comment: The USGS site seems broken at the moment and I can't get the data. Its possible your file is incomplete or corrupted?

Comment: Anything is possible :) The rest of the data seems fine. There is another gdb in the same package that has the same problem.

Comment: If it extracted from a zip then its probably okay, zip will have done a checksum test. Site was up long enough for me to download and I get the same errors.

Comment: Yes, I think it's some ArcGIS versioning thing that QGIS can't use :/

Comment: Can you post your QGIS version as well? It might be an older version which didn't fully support FGBD.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations are (as far as I know) a specific ESRI format (it's something that can be described as "geographic text", meaning it's a text but it behave more like vector feature).

QGIS cant use this specific format and will only display polygon (likely the oriented bounding box of each annotation). By using label with data defined properties based on the annotation class field you should be able to achieve something close (but as this will be label they will now always be displayed on top). It may be as easy to just create your label based on the shapefile (if the relevant information are in the .shp attribute table).

That being said you shouldn't see any error when you try to add it, you may try to use the browser panel to navigate to the annotation class and adding from there. If it still didn't work either your data are corrupt or this ESRI GDB is not QGIS compatible (I think QGIS can't use 9.x file GDB or compressed file GDB).

Comment: Unfortunately the shapefiles only contain information on the type of rock in each polygon - the annotations label each crater/feature with their name. The impression I get from an afternoon of Googling is that something in this particular version of GDB doesn't play well with QGIS.